# negative RSquare for test data, while train data RSquare is good

Tags: python, sklearn-pandas

I am new to linear model , train_test_split in sklearn.model_selection

I follow a standard "format/procedure" to train a model for an input CSV file related to housing information.

The input CSV file contains following fields :

1. "month" : a string indicating transaction year and month
2. "flat_type" : either 3-ROOM or 4-ROOM
3. "block": block number as string
4. "street_name": string
5. "storey_range": an integer derived from a storey_range, e.g. floor 5 to floor 7 will give average of 6
6. "floor_area_sqm": integer indicating the floor area
7. "lease_commence_date": year where the flat begin its lease
8. "resale_price": price sold in resale market, this field is the target of the data model, suppose to predict the future resale price.

the CSV data is as follows :

```
month,flat_type,block,street_name,storey_range,floor_area_sqm,lease_commence_date,resale_price
2012-04,3 ROOM,95,OLD AIRPORT RD,8,56,1969,355000
2012-10,3 ROOM,95,OLD AIRPORT RD,8,56,1969,350000
2013-04,3 ROOM,95,OLD AIRPORT RD,5,56,1969,365000
2013-05,3 ROOM,95,OLD AIRPORT RD,5,56,1969,343000
2014-06,3 ROOM,95,OLD AIRPORT RD,8,56,1969,355000
2015-09,3 ROOM,95,OLD AIRPORT RD,11,56,1969,278000
2015-11,3 ROOM,95,OLD AIRPORT RD,2,56,1969,288000
2015-12,3 ROOM,95,OLD AIRPORT RD,8,56,1969,320000
2016-01,3 ROOM,95,OLD AIRPORT RD,5,56,1969,312000
2016-02,3 ROOM,95,OLD AIRPORT RD,2,53,1969,288000
2017-01,3 ROOM,95,OLD AIRPORT RD,8,56,1969,330000
2017-03,3 ROOM,95,OLD AIRPORT RD,5,56,1969,316000
2017-03,3 ROOM,95,OLD AIRPORT RD,5,56,1969,320000
2017-07,3 ROOM,95,OLD AIRPORT RD,8,56,1969,335000
2017-10,3 ROOM,95,OLD AIRPORT RD,5,56,1969,318888
2018-07,3 ROOM,95,OLD AIRPORT RD,8,56,1969,287000
2019-05,3 ROOM,95,OLD AIRPORT RD,8,56,1969,288000
2019-07,3 ROOM,95,OLD AIRPORT RD,5,56,1969,250000
2012-04,3 ROOM,99,OLD AIRPORT RD,3,56,1969,345000
2012-07,3 ROOM,99,OLD AIRPORT RD,5,56,1969,350000
2012-08,3 ROOM,99,OLD AIRPORT RD,2,56,1969,325000
2012-12,3 ROOM,99,OLD AIRPORT RD,2,56,1969,350000
2013-01,3 ROOM,99,OLD AIRPORT RD,5,56,1969,350000
2013-03,3 ROOM,99,OLD AIRPORT RD,11,56,1969,388000
2013-05,3 ROOM,99,OLD AIRPORT RD,8,56,1969,374000
2013-08,3 ROOM,99,OLD AIRPORT RD,5,56,1969,340000
2014-06,3 ROOM,99,OLD AIRPORT RD,5,56,1969,330000
2015-06,3 ROOM,99,OLD AIRPORT RD,8,56,1969,320000
2015-06,3 ROOM,99,OLD AIRPORT RD,8,56,1969,325000
2015-09,3 ROOM,99,OLD AIRPORT RD,8,56,1969,320000
2016-03,3 ROOM,99,OLD AIRPORT RD,11,56,1969,318000
2018-03,3 ROOM,99,OLD AIRPORT RD,8,56,1969,315000
2018-04,3 ROOM,99,OLD AIRPORT RD,5,56,1969,308000
2018-10,3 ROOM,99,OLD AIRPORT RD,5,56,1969,285000
2018-11,3 ROOM,99,OLD AIRPORT RD,5,56,1969,310000
2019-04,3 ROOM,99,OLD AIRPORT RD,11,56,1969,292000
2019-07,3 ROOM,99,OLD AIRPORT RD,8,56,1969,342000
2012-04,3 ROOM,44,OWEN RD,8,67,1979,392000
2012-11,3 ROOM,44,OWEN RD,2,67,1979,403000
2014-01,4 ROOM,44,OWEN RD,5,92,1979,495000
2014-04,3 ROOM,44,OWEN RD,8,67,1979,403000
2016-01,3 ROOM,44,OWEN RD,2,67,1979,360000
2016-10,3 ROOM,44,OWEN RD,5,67,1979,360000
2017-07,4 ROOM,44,OWEN RD,8,92,1979,505000
2017-09,3 ROOM,44,OWEN RD,5,67,1979,330000
2018-04,3 ROOM,44,OWEN RD,2,82,1979,448000
2019-02,4 ROOM,44,OWEN RD,2,92,1979,401000
2019-05,3 ROOM,44,OWEN RD,8,67,1979,360000
2020-07,3 ROOM,44,OWEN RD,5,82,1979,390000
2012-09,4 ROOM,46,OWEN RD,5,92,1982,540000
2012-10,3 ROOM,46,OWEN RD,5,68,1982,405000
2012-11,3 ROOM,46,OWEN RD,5,68,1982,435000
2014-02,3 ROOM,46,OWEN RD,8,68,1982,400000
2014-03,3 ROOM,46,OWEN RD,2,68,1982,380000
2014-10,3 ROOM,46,OWEN RD,5,68,1982,393000
2015-08,3 ROOM,46,OWEN RD,2,68,1982,360000
2017-01,3 ROOM,46,OWEN RD,8,68,1982,372000
2017-08,3 ROOM,46,OWEN RD,8,68,1982,367777
2018-06,4 ROOM,46,OWEN RD,5,92,1982,480000
2020-08,3 ROOM,46,OWEN RD,5,68,1982,358000
```

the python code (ipynb file) used in jupyter lab is as follows:

```
def extract_block(inblk):
    blkstr = str(inblk).strip()
    if len(blkstr) <= 0:
        return ""
    return str(blkstr[:3])
    
                
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import linear_model
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
    
f  = pd.read_csv(r'c:\users\user\downloads\resaleprice\o_streets.csv')
for i in range(len(f)):
   f.at[i,"street_name"] = f.street_name[i]+ extract_block(f.block[i])
    
f.index = range(len(f))
        
x_cat = pd.DataFrame({"flat_type":f.flat_type,"street_name":f.street_name,"month":f.month})
x_dummy = pd.get_dummies(data=x_cat, drop_first=True)
x_val = pd.DataFrame({"floor_area":f.floor_area_sqm, "lease_commence_date":f.lease_commence_date, "storey_range":f.storey_range})
x_dummy = x_dummy.join(x_val)
x = x_dummy
y = f.resale_price
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.2)
lm = linear_model.LinearRegression()
lm.fit(x,y)

print("\nWithout train_test_split , merely use x,y directly in model , score is", lm.score(x,y), "\n")
#preprocess x_train

scaler = StandardScaler()
val_features = x_train[["floor_area", "lease_commence_date", "storey_range"]]
new_val_features =scaler.fit_transform(val_features.values)
del x_train['floor_area']
del x_train['lease_commence_date']
del x_train['storey_range']
new_features_df = pd.DataFrame(data= new_val_features,columns= ["floor_area", "lease_commence_date", "storey_range"])
x_train.index = range(len(x_train))
x_train = x_train.join(new_features_df)

model = lm.fit(x_train,y_train)
    
print('Intercept = ', lm.intercept_)
coeff_df = pd.DataFrame(lm.coef_, x.columns, columns=['Coefficient'])
print('Cofficients = ', coeff_df)
predictions = lm.predict(x_test)
    
print("test data r2 ", lm.score(x_test,y_test), " Train data r2 ", lm.score(x_train, y_train))
```

In the code, I append the first 3 characters of the "block" field to the "street_name" field.

categorical fields are "flat_type", "street_name", "month", they are used in get_dummies function.
numeric fields "floor_area", "lease_commence_date", "storey_range" are numeric features for the data model.
So a total of 6 features.

The output of running the python script are as follows :

```
Without train_test_split , merely use x,y directly in model , score is 0.9846803871636114 

Intercept =  381533.21266032214
Cofficients =                                 Coefficient
flat_type_4 ROOM             -8.557333e+04
street_name_OLD AIRPORT RD99  2.033333e+04
street_name_OWEN RD44         6.169080e+02
street_name_OWEN RD46        -2.024686e+03
month_2012-07                 1.166667e+04
month_2012-08                 2.366667e+04
month_2012-09                 3.670667e+04
month_2012-10                -8.333333e+02
month_2012-11                 3.750000e+04
month_2012-12                 4.866667e+04
month_2013-01                -6.361915e-10
month_2013-03                 1.091394e-10
month_2013-04                 4.874892e-10
month_2013-05                 1.183333e+04
month_2013-08                 1.666667e+03
month_2014-01                -1.276000e+04
month_2014-02                -3.866667e+04
month_2014-03                 1.533333e+04
month_2014-04                -3.233333e+04
month_2014-06                -4.166667e+03
month_2014-10                -8.666667e+03
month_2015-06                -5.283333e+04
month_2015-08                -4.666667e+03
month_2015-09                -5.533333e+04
month_2015-11                 7.000000e+03
month_2015-12                -3.500000e+04
month_2016-01                -1.333333e+03
month_2016-02                 3.040000e+04
month_2016-03                 1.455192e-11
month_2016-10                -3.833333e+04
month_2017-01                -6.666667e+04
month_2017-03                 2.255547e-10
month_2017-07                -3.976000e+04
month_2017-08                -7.088967e+04
month_2017-09                -6.833333e+04
month_2017-10                 8.880000e+02
month_2018-03                -6.033333e+04
month_2018-04                -3.033333e+04
month_2018-06                 1.273293e-11
month_2018-07                 1.031708e-11
month_2018-10                -5.333333e+04
month_2018-11                -2.833333e+04
month_2019-02                -6.976000e+04
month_2019-04                -1.203333e+05
month_2019-05                -7.116667e+04
month_2019-07                -5.066667e+04
month_2020-07                -1.253333e+05
month_2020-08                -4.366667e+04
floor_area                    8.545198e+04
lease_commence_date          -3.501360e+03
storey_range                  2.891396e+04
test data r2  -1104.8440189559208  Train data r2  0.9929579455753994
```

I cannot figure out why train data is GOOD, 0.9929
while test data selected by train_test_split() function give a very high -ve value for RSquare ?

Comment: it is rsqure not correlation coefficient. and can you focus your post to 1 question? If there are other questions, put them into another post

Comment: and seems like something is terribly wrong, your intercept is 1e+18 while your target values are not in that range.. can you scale your data first

Comment: @StupidWolf, sorry I don't understand what you mean by "scale my data first" ? do you mean change the resale price manually ?

Comment: you have some continuous independent variables in x_val, can you do center and scale, https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.scale.html#sklearn.preprocessing.scale

Comment: @StupidWolf, I took a while to figure out (google) how to "center and scale", but not sure if this is correct ?